# How can one control occupy two rows in TableLayout

Tags: android

My question is quiet simple.

How can a `View`, like an `ImageView` occupy two rows in a `TableLayout`?

I search a lot for the answer but I couldn't find anything.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with a `TableLayout`, they only support column spans. But you can use a `GridLayout` instead! Try something like this:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2" />

    ...

</GridLayout>
```

---

To define how many rows and columns there are use these two attributes on the `GridLayout`:

- `android:columnCount`
- `android:rowCount`

You can define the position of a `View` inside the `GridLayout` with these two attributes:

- `android:layout_column`
- `android:layout_row`

And you can define how many rows or columns a `View` spans with these two attributes:

- `android:layout_rowSpan`
- `android:layout_columnSpan`

---

Please note that the `GridLayout` was only added with API level 14! If you want to use the `GridLayout` in earlier versions you need to use the `GridLayout` from the support library:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...    

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```